# How to add resume in amazon polly's text to speech in android?

Tags: android, amazon-polly

I am using `Amazon Polly` , and I want to resume pronounced `speech` where it was paused but it starts from beginning whenever i tried to resume. I set source in `media player` as follows

> mediaPlayer.setDataSource(presignedSynthesizeSpeechUrl.toString());

The code I tried to use pause and resume is as follows,

```
playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(pauseVal){
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                pauseVal = false;
            }else{
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                length= mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                pauseVal = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

I am stuck here , can't move further with resume functionality. I will be thankful if any of you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media player doesn't support resume functionality for passed URL . since I was using webview so I just passed that URL to Audio tag which supports resume functionality.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp